# How to show Woocommerce excerpt, short description, only on desktop and hide it on mobile and tablet?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a code to show product excrept, the short description of the product on Woocommerce Shop page. It works fine, but I'm struggling witn an idea, how to show the content only on desktop and hide it on mobile and tablet?

**Code bellow**

```
function show_product_description_et_shop() {
if(class_exists('WooCommerce')) {
$output = get_the_excerpt();
echo '
<div class="car-description">'.$output.'</div>
';
}
}

function load_function_after_wc(){

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'show_product_description_et_shop', 100 );
}

add_action('wp_loaded', 'load_function_after_wc');
```

I'll be very grateful for any suggestions and solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this with css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
    div.car-description {
        display: none!important;
    }
}
```